# table in wrong place in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web

I have a problem where everything looks as expected in Chrome and Firefox but when I open my homepage in IE, I have two tables in particular that shift to the left quite a bit. One part of the table kind of stays in place but the rest of it moves...seems really odd to me.

How can I make these tables stay in the same place? Is there any attribute I can use to keep the tables in fixed places?

Cheers guys

looks like this in chrome

[image]

and this in IE

[image]

Comment: What about posting some code?

Comment: I'm creating this in dreamweaver, i'm using a widget providing twitter feeds in a table, the html code is large and looks really messy. Is there any tags or attributes I can use to keep the table intact? Thanks

Comment: See if you can post from a <div> tag surrounding the table through two or three rows of the table.  That would give us something to go on.  Otherwise we can't do much other than refer you to www.quirksmode.com

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you mean a <div> tag surround the whole table or say just around 3 of the 5 rows in the table. I've tried a <div> tag around the whole table and it had no effect :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look at your code and see if the individual columns have width set to it.

One scenario where one part of table stay in place, the rest of it moves could be due to the part that stays has width style added to it, while the rest does not have any width style.

If the above scenario is the one that applies, you can easily set the individual column width by giving a style - style="width: XXX px;"

Answer (score 0):

This is why you need an online account. Anything we say is all guesswork. The fact that IE is not acting like the other far more modern browsers is expected. Are you using a doctype? Without one, you are in quirks mode.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked into it and its when I insert the widget that it begins behaving differently in IE. If I leave the widget out the tables stay the same across the browsers. It must be an issue with the widget so